# How to optimize mysql query using php/mysql eager loading or similar approach

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2, eager-loading

I have 2 tables. 1 - "cpv" ; 2 - "club_offer_cpv".

In table "cpv" I am storing CPV codes, their ids and names. You can see CPV codes [here](http://www.bipsolutions.com/cpvtool/bip-cpv-search-tool.html). There are 6 levels of CPV codes, as you can see by visiting the link provided.

In CPV table there are fields : "id" and "name".

Here are few examples of first level CPVs ( we can call them root CPVs ):

id: 03000000
name: Agricultural, farming, fishing, forestry and related products

id: 09000000
name: Petroleum products, fuel, electricity and other sources of energy

There are 45 root CPVs, and they have their children. Hierarchy of their IDs is very strict as you can see from the link I provided to you. For example, root CPV 03000000 have second level children:

03100000 : Agricultural and horticultural products
03200000 : Cereals, potatoes, vegetables, fruits and nuts
03300000 : Farming, hunting and fishing products
03400000 : Forestry and logging products

Now, for every CPV there is company that is doing business in that field ( company is providing offers for that field ), For example, for

03100000 : Agricultural and horticultural products

There are few companies whose business is to create food, and that is why they are connected to this cpv. Those companies offers are stored in different table "company_offer", but that is not important now. Important is that there is table "company_offer_cpv" that is connecting company_offer and cpv tables.

"company_offer_cpv" table have these fields:

"id", "company_offer_id", "cpv_id". This is how I can connect companies with cpv codes of their fields, since they can have many codes assigned to them.

What I want to do is to count all CPVs used in company_offer_cpv table for each CPV group and display those numbers next to group ( when I say group I mean root cpv ) name. Like this :

03000000 : Agricultural, farming, fishing, forestry and related products : 240
09000000 : Petroleum products, fuel, electricity and other sources of energy : 130
14000000 : Mining, basic metals and related products : 72

And so on...

I am using yii2 php framework, but if you are not using it it doesn't matter, you can help me with mysql/php code.

To count number of all CPVs used in table company_offer_cpv, and to display them as stated above, I am using this code:

```
$total = ClubOfferCpv::find()->groupBy( ['LEFT(cpv_id, 2)'] )
                             ->select( ['LEFT(cpv_id, 2) AS cpv_id', 'COUNT(cpv_id) AS count'])
                             ->all();

foreach ($total as $data) 
{
    $id = $data->cpv_id."000000";

    $cpvName = Cpv::find()->select('name')->where(['id' => $id])->one();

    echo $cpvName->name. " " . $data->count;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

But there is one flaw in my code ( or more :) ). If you look inside foreach loop, I am executing this line of code to get all root cpv names so I can display them next to count numbers:

$cpvName = Cpv::find()->select('name')->where(['id' => $id])->one();

Since there are 45 root CPVs, this line will result in 45 queries executed. I need to make it 1 or 2 queries in total, but I do not know how. I know that Yii2 is providing [Eager Loading](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#lazy-and-eager-loading) but I do not know how to use it. Do anyone know how I can, using yii2 or just plain sql/php, solve this problem ?

This is sql executed by first line of code :

```
SELECT LEFT(cpv_id, 2) AS cpv_id, COUNT(cpv_id) AS count FROM `club_offer_cpv` GROUP BY LEFT(cpv_id, 2)
```

And this is one of SQLs executed by line inside foreach:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `cpv` WHERE `id`='50000000'
```

Thank you in advance

---

Here is an update made to reply nicely to JC Sama's help:

If I try with yii2 eager loading as you said, I do not get any result because I need to trim cpv_id's from my company_offer_cpv table. Here are the queries executed by eager:

```
SELECT LEFT(cpv_id, 2) AS cpv_id, COUNT(cpv_id) AS count FROM `club_offer_cpv` GROUP BY LEFT(cpv_id, 2) ;
```

and second:

```
SELECT * FROM `cpv` WHERE `id` IN ('03', '09', '14', '15', '16', '18', '19', '22', '24', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '37', '38', '39', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '48', '50', '51', '55', '60', '63', '64', '65', '66', '70', '71', '72', '73', '75', '76', '77', '79', '80', '85', '90', '92', '98')
```

---

Thank you a lot JC Sama !

Here is the full solution:

```
$total = ClubOfferCpv::find()->groupBy( ['LEFT(cpv_id, 2)'] )
                             ->select( ['LEFT(cpv_id, 2) AS cpv', 'CONCAT(LEFT(cpv_id, 2), "000000") AS cpv_id', 'COUNT(cpv_id) AS count'])
                             ->with('cpv')
                             ->all();

foreach ($total as $data) 
{
    echo $data->cpv->name. " " . $data->count;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Yii but according to the documentation, you could try something like this :

```
$total = ClubOfferCpv::find()->groupBy( ['LEFT(cpv_id, 2)'] )
                             ->select( ['LEFT(cpv_id, 2) AS cpv', 'CONCAT(LEFT(cpv_id, 2), "000000") AS cpv_id', 'COUNT(cpv_id) AS count'])
                             ->with('cpv')
                             ->all();
```

Or you can use `WHERE IN()` statment for your second query like this, because the idea is the same using Eager loading :

```
$ids = array();
foreach ($total as $data) 
{
    $id[] = $data->cpv_id."000000";
}
```

and then :

```
// I'm not sure about WhereIn() Yii stuff :)
$cpvNames = Cpv::find()->select('name, id')->where(['id' => $ids])->all();
// Create an associative array, not sure how it's done with Yii
$cpvNames = CHtml::listData( $cpvNames, 'id' , 'name');
```

Finally :

```
foreach ($total as $data) {

    $id = $data->cpv_id."000000";
    echo $cpvNames[$id]. " " . $data->count;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Recap :
You will end up with just 2 queries :

```
SELECT LEFT(cpv_id, 2) AS cpv_id, COUNT(cpv_id) AS count FROM `club_offer_cpv` GROUP BY LEFT(cpv_id, 2)
```

And the second one using `where in` instead of `equal`

```
SELECT `name` FROM `cpv` WHERE `id` in ('50000000', 800000, ...)
```

Comment: If I try with yii2 eager loading as you said, I do not get any result because I need to trim cpv_id's in my company_offer_cpv table. Here are the queries executed by eager: SELECT LEFT(cpv_id, 2) AS cpv_id, COUNT(cpv_id) AS count FROM `club_offer_cpv` GROUP BY LEFT(cpv_id, 2) ; and second: SELECT * FROM `cpv` WHERE `id` IN ('03', '09', '14', '15', '16', '18', '19', '22', '24', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '37', '38', '39', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '48', '50', '51', '55', '60', '63', '64', '65', '66', '70', '71', '72', '73', '75', '76', '77', '79', '80', '85', '90', '92', '98')

Comment: First with yii2 eager loading, because in second you are showing code from yii1, and I do not know how to use it. I have edited my post, please read the end.

Comment: It's the same idea, which is using ÌN` keyword instead of `=` in the second query, you can translate it to Yii code. Anyway, It's working but you have te remove the `LEFT` keyword

Comment: If I remove LEFT I still do not get result, since this is the query: SELECT * FROM `cpv` WHERE `id` IN ('03441000', '09100000', '14212310', '15861100', '16400000', '18000000', '19212200', '22460000', '24453000', '30200000', '31625300', '32323500', '33111500', '34110000', '35127500', '37442810', '38436710', '39251100', '41110000', '42961300', '43000000', '44112200', '45312200', '48100000', '50111100', '51430000', '55330000', '60100000', '63710000', '64121000', '65210000', '66112000', '70123200', '71317200', '72212321', '73431000', '75250000', '76410000', '77310000', '79212110', '80411100')

Comment: For example, there is no parent 03441000, there is 03000000

Comment: I will try now, your no yii2 answer, maybe I make it right.

Comment: check my answer I did change `whereIn` for Yii2

Comment: $total = ClubOfferCpv::find()->groupBy( ['LEFT(cpv_id, 2)'] )
                             ->select( ['LEFT(cpv_id, 2) AS cpv', 'CONCAT(LEFT(cpv_id, 2), '000000') AS cpv_id', 'COUNT(cpv_id) AS count'])
                             ->with('cpv')
                             ->all();

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '000000' (T_LNUMBER), expecting ']'

Comment: Bingo! Insted of '000000' just put "000000". Thank you a lot ! You saved my life, I wish I can buy you a lunch or something... wow